# Captive runtime packaging issue (Failed to load the AIR Runtime) under Catalina 10.15.7 with ADT

Tags: macos, flash, apache-flex, air, adt

I am trying to package my AIR app on mac (Catalina 10.15.7) with ADT after successful compilation step.
Everything is fine with the .air package on mac and with both .air and .exe under Windows.
But for .dmg and captive runtime bundle (.app) I get next error after several seconds of doing something:

**Failed to load the AIR Runtime**

Ant command:

```
/opt/flexsdk15/bin/adt -package -storetype pkcs12 -keystore myCert.p12 -storepass ******** -tsa http://time.certum.pl -target native bin/myApp.dmg src/myApp-app.xml -C bin myApp.swf -C . icons
```

SDK used: Apache Flex 4.15.0 FP20.0 AIR20.0

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try to upgrade AIR SDK. V20 is way to old

Comment: Thanks for answering. As it often happens I managed to resolve the issue myself right after posting a question. It started to package without issues when I updated to the Flex SDK 4.16.1 overlaid with the AIR SDK 32.

Comment: yep, it simply because you are running on Catalina while AIR 20 is too old for that. Glad that the problem has been resolved.